# alternative bulk insert from vb to sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

i need to make a bulk insert from vb to sql, i have two ways : `SqlBulkCopy` and pass table as parameter to the stored procedure , but i'm facing a timeout exception with these two methods for huge data.. is there any other way to prevent a for loop from vb to sql and to prevent a timeout and cpu usage on sql.

Comment: Only SqlBulkCopy actually does bulk insert. The stored procedure would do this only if you used the `BULK INSERT` statement - which only reads files. It's equivalent to the `bcp` command line utility. As for the timeout- what timeout? Command or connection? If it's command, just increase it. Check this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535536/timeout-expired-with-sqlbulkcopy) question

Comment: Also, depending on your timeouts, you could try inserting a smaller chuck of data at a time.